# How to add a field to an enterprise geodatabase feature class

Tags: arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase

I need to add a field to a feature class in my enterprise geodatabase, I haven't needed to add a field since my company switched to ArcGIS Pro. I can't add a field from the attribute table. I'm assuming it needs to be done through catalog view. I see where to edit domains, but not where to edit fields.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. If the table isn't versioned, you have multiple options. If versioned, it's trickier. Please [Edit] the Question to indicate the versioning of the FC.

Answer (score 0):

To do this I would use the [Add Field (Data Management)](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/add-field.htm) geoprocessing tool but that is just one of several ways to do it if you have write access to your Enterprise Geodatabase.